# How to add row of total and percentage in list of data table in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of a data table that wants two rows 1. total  2. percentage for each data table.
Here just added a sample.  what I want to add the fourth row of totals to sum the columns y and z, not PROVINCE and the fifth row of percentage.

```
#> [[1]]
#>   PROVINCE         Y        Z
#> 1        2  89.98376 90.79929
#> 2        2  97.12802 90.68774
#> 3        4 100.62682 91.20288
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   PROVINCE         Y         Z
#> 1        4 106.09127  94.19237
#> 2        6 111.30426 107.42695
#> 3        5  84.44623 102.04221
```

Comment: please add a small reproducible example using `dput` and not as images along with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have tidy data.

```
data <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
id <- rownames(data)
new_data <- cbind(id,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of sim235

```
papa$ID <- 1:nrow(papa)
```